# Nested MAX causes smallest value to sometimes be returned when using various object types - MAX(a,MAX(b,c))

Tags: objective-c, integer, max, integer-overflow

I was debugging a while before I found that one of my integers defined as MAX(2,x) was returning -4 even though 2 is clearly larger than -4.

Here is a simplified version of what my code was running so you can experience the irregularity first hand.

```
    NSLog(@"a) %i", (int)MAX(2,-4));
    NSString *aString = @"90586381095716439405631195482586763570805293418319186736659080000000000000";
    int aNumber = (int)MAX(2,10-MAX(1,(aString.length/5)));
    NSLog(@"b) %i", aNumber);
    NSLog(@"c) %i", (int)MAX(2,10-MAX(1,16)));
```

a) will log 2 as expected.

b) will log -4 which makes no sense to me.

c) will log 2 as expected (now b makes even less sense to me)

---

What am I not getting? MAX is brown in xCode which makes me think it's set as CLANG somewhere in UIKit or Math library, if that's the case perhaps the inner MAX gets processed only after the first MAX has been processed and therefor nesting MAXs will result in weird bugs. But if that were the case wouldn't c) have also logged -4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Objective-C, but the `length` of the string is probably an unsigned value. If it works the same way as plain C, that would cause the result of the inner `MAX` to be unsigned as well, and therefore the subtraction from 10 will be performed as unsigned. This will cause the value to underflow and result in a very large value, something like 4294967292 assuming 32 bit ints, and therefore it will be chosen by the outer `MAX`.

The final `int` is what then converts it back to signed and you end up with a negative value. If your compiler is any good and you leave the `(int)` out, you should get a warning about it.

Moral of the story, don't use extraneous casts, that causes the compiler to not give you valuable warnings.

Comment: Wow you're right, casting `(int)` to the string.length fixed the problem. `(int)aString.length` - and also in case c) casting `(NSUInteger)`, which is what .length is, to the `16` reproduced the issue. So MAX has issues handling `NSUInteger`, interesting..

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: It really has nothing to do with `MAX`. The problem is the subtraction. If you're going to be subtracting unsigned values and don't want underflow, you need to check your values before subtracting.

Comment: Not necessarily, if I check the value before applying MAX the problem fixes itself. If I defined the MAX(b,c) as an integer "d", and then do MAX(a,d) it does return a. So it seems to be an issue with the logic behind processing MAX when NSUinteger is involved. Processing the NSUinteger before hand and putting it in max (or checking the value before hand, and then putting that in max) prevents the issue. Hmm

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: What is "processing an integer"?

Comment: Sorry I meant processing the nested MAX's internal values and converting storing as integers.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: So by processing you meant casting. What happens inside `MAX` is exactly the same as if you did a comparison with, say, `<`. If you compare a signed value (e.g. a plain literal such as 2) with an unsigned value (e.g. your length calculation which ends up being unsigned), both are converted to **unsigned** before comparing. It's just how comparisons work in C, and it's not an issue with `MAX`.

Comment: Nit: this is still "overflow", not "underflow", even though it's going around the bottom. Underflow really only applies to floats very close to 0.